# ListView Adapter setResult() and Finish() error

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to startActivity for Result by using startActivityForResult() method.Now the activity which get started has a listview  with adapter class for it.I had wriiten following Listview Adapter so when user selects any item it should return back to calling activity with selected item name.I cant able to call 2 methods

```
setResult() and finish() in following code
```

Adapter Code:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            SharedPreferences prefernces = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyKey111", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefernces.edit();
            editor1.putString("Custname",customerpopulationlist.get(position).getName());
            editor1.putString("let_id", customerpopulationlist.get(position).getLetId());
            editor1.commit();

            Intent intentMessage = new Intent();

            // put the message in Intent
            intentMessage.putExtra("MESSAGE", "hello");
            intentMessage.putExtra("selected_refer", customerpopulationlist.get(position).getLetId());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, intentMessage);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must hold an reference to your activity that created the adapter then set result to that. the thing you are doing is setting the result of OnClickListener object !!

add an Activity object to your adapter constructor and save it in a local variable in adapter and call it **act** then call the **setResult()** of the activtiy like below:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        SharedPreferences prefernces = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyKey111", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefernces.edit();
        editor1.putString("Custname",customerpopulationlist.get(position).getName());
        editor1.putString("let_id", customerpopulationlist.get(position).getLetId());
        editor1.commit();

        Intent intentMessage = new Intent();

        // put the message in Intent
        intentMessage.putExtra("MESSAGE", "hello");
        intentMessage.putExtra("selected_refer", customerpopulationlist.get(position).getLetId());

        //THESE TWO LINES NEED TO BE CHANGED
        act.setResult(RESULT_OK, intentMessage);
        act.finish();

    }
});
```

Comment: I tried using Context of the activity bu it doesnt work,How to pass reference of the activity

Answer (score 1):

You need `override` method `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, intent data` on the activity you need to return to i.e. the activity where you have called `startActivityforResult()`.

```
  @override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, intent data){
    if(resultCode == -1) // -1 for RESULT_OK
    { // your logic goes here...
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between an Activity object and A Context object(if there is confusion, better read the documentation for better understanding) So, the answer is simple,

When you want to do an activity based operation, follow like this

```
Activity activity = this; 
Context context = ActivityName.this;
```

Pass both the objects in the adapter and then use

```
activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent); 
activity.finish();
```

and for context-based operations use Intent i = new Intent( ListViewAdapter.this.mContext,EventPrivacyAndTicketPrice.class);

see full activity code below:

```
    public class ActivityX extends AppCompatActivity {
Intent intent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_x);
        intent = getIntent();
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_x);
        ArrayList<ETypeObject> allTypes= new ArrayList<>();
        allTypes = GetData();

        ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter= new       ListViewAdapter(allTypes,ActivityX.this,intent,this);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    }

    public ArrayList<ETypeObject> GetData(){
        ArrayList<ETypeObject> allTypes= new ArrayList<>();
        allTypes.add(new ETypeObject("Object1",0));
        allTypes.add(new ETypeObject("Object2, Talk",0));
        allTypes.add(new ETypeObject("Object3",0));

   return allTypes;
    }


}

class ETypeObject {
   public String name;
    public int imageId;

    public ETypeObject(String name, int imageId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public ETypeObject() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
}




 class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Activity activity;
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ETypeObject> allTypes= new ArrayList<>();
    Intent intent;
    public ListViewAdapter(){}

    public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<ETypeObject> AllTypes, Context context,Intent intent,Activity activity){
        mContext = context;
        allTypes = AllTypes;
        activity =activity;
        this.intent = intent;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allTypes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return allTypes.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i1, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (layoutInflater!=null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay1,null);

        }

        TextView type;


        type = view.findViewById(R.id.parentInteresttext);

        type.setText(allTypes.get(i1).getName());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // Toast.makeText(mContext,allTypes.get(i1).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra("fromThirdActivty",false)){

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("eventType",allTypes.get(i1).getName());
                    activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
                    activity.finish();

                }


                Intent i = new Intent( ListViewAdapter.this.mContext,OtherActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("eventType",allTypes.get(i1).getName());
                ListViewAdapter.this.mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```